# Evaluating an indefinite integral using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

Using tools from complex analysis, I have to prove that

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\,dx = - \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

But I'm not really sure where I should start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The basic idea is to integrate $\frac{\ln(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}$ (using the principal branch of the logarithm) over a keyhole contour which avoids the negative real axis, then use the residue theorem.

Comment: @carmichael561 Actually, one needs to analyze the key-hole contour integral $$\oint_C \frac{\log^2(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz$$

Comment: @ Dr. MV: good point. I suppose that's what I get for not working it out.

Comment: @carmichael561 It is interesting that analysis of the integral of $\frac{\log^n(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}$ around the keyhole facilitates evaluating the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^{n-1}(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be the classical key-hole contour and $I$ be the integral

$$\begin{align}I&=\oint_C \frac{\log^2(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^R \frac{\log^2(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx+\int_R^0 \frac{(\log(x)+i2\pi)^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\log^2(Re^{i\phi})}{(R^2e^{i2\phi}+1)^2}iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-i4\pi\int_0^R\frac{\log(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx+\int_0^R\frac{4\pi^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\log^2(Re^{i\phi})}{(R^2e^{i2\phi}+1)^2}iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 1
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$ the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches the integral of interest, the second integral approaches $\pi^3$, and the third approaches $0$.

In addition, from the residue theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}, z=\pm i \right)\\\\
&=2\pi i\left(\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi^2}{16}\right)+\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}-i\frac{9\pi^2}{16}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\pi^3+i\pi^2 \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Setting $(1)$ equal to $(2)$, we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Great! I also just discovered that this computation is also given here, in Example V: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration

Comment: Interesting; that development used the branch cut on the negative real axis.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how you calculated those residues? For some reason I'm getting slightly different answers.

Comment: Sure.  $$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}, z=\pm i\right)=\lim_{z\to\pm i}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{\log^2(z)}{(z\pm i)^2}\right)$$And remember $\log(i)=i\pi/2$ and $\log(-i)=i3\pi/2$.